# Handle long min value condition

Tags: java

When I ran a program, long min value is getting persisted instead of original value coming from the backend.

I am using the code:

```
if (columnName.equals(Fields.NOTIONAL)) {
            orderData.notional(getNewValue(data));
```

As output of this, i am getting long min value, instead of original value.

I tried using this method to handle the scenario

```
public String getNewValue(Object data) {
        return ((Long)data).getLong("0")==Long.MIN_VALUE?"":((Long)data).toString();
    }
```

but doesn't work.

Please suggest

Comment: Long.getLong it is a static method that checks the value of a systemProperty with name "0", are you sure you want this? is data a Long object? if yes why you want to call getLong?

Comment: If column is getting some value, then that must be persisted but instead of original value, long min value is being persisted so, I write the second block to handle that condition but that also doesn't work

Comment: What do you expect to get with this: `((Long)data).getLong("0")`? Could it be that you misuse `getLong` instead of `parseLong`?

Comment: From backend value stored is 0N and when I try to persist at my end it is coming as long min value and I want to get it stored as 0. So, I was just trying different approaches to get data corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED: I misread the code in the question; rereading it, I now get what the author is trying to do, and cleaned up the suggestion as a consequence.

`(Long) data).getLong("0")` is a silly way to write `null`, because that doesn't do anything. It retrieves the system property named '0', and then attempts to parse it as a Long value. As in, if you start your VM with `java -D0=1234 com.foo.YourClass`, that returns 1234. I don't even know what you're attempting to accomplish with this call. Obviously it is not equal to `Long.MIN_VALUE`, thus the method returns ((Long) data).toString(). If `data` is in fact a Long representing MIN_VALUE, you'll get the digits of MIN_VALUE, clearly not what you wanted.

Try this:

```
public String getNewValue(Object data) {
    if (data instanceof Number) {
        long v = ((Number) data).longValue();
        return v == Long.MIN_VALUE ? "" : data.toString();
    }
// what do you want to return if the input isn't a numeric object at all?
    return "";
```

Comment: From backend value stored is 0N and when I try to persist at my end it is coming as long min value and I want to get it stored as0

Comment: From backend value is: 0N but when I ran the code, value persisted at my end is: -9223372036854775808. When i analyse it further I found this is long min value not the actual value coming from backend

Comment: I explained exactly what is wrong with your code. If you don't get it, perhaps find a java programmer who can follow along? I don't know how to explain it any better.